# Elastic Search High Level Client - How to search with Post Request?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have used Elastic Search High Level Client to search the elastic index and process the results. I have used the following code to do the same.

```
restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

However, rest client uses "GET" to query the data. However, I want to send this as a Post request to Elastic Search. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use POST instead of GET?

Comment: @dadoonet I have facets and filters enabled in my application. The number of items they can select can go up to 200 to 300 items and hence, the length of the query string might exceed 2000 characters.

Comment: We are using GET with BODY so there is no limit AFAIK (but 100mb HTTP limit)

Comment: @dadoonet Thank you for your response.  So we can continue to use highLevelClient.search().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion (see comments), there was no need to force the High Level Rest Client to use `POST` instead of `GET` as `GET` is using behind the scene `GET with body`.